# Como pegar div através de outra classe

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Tenho um `.aspx` onde coloquei uma `div` de alerta. Tenho uma classe `Message` para tratar as mensagens do sistema. Para tratar essas mensagens ao instanciar a classe, passo como parâmetro a página, no método passo como parâmetro a mensagem e tipo de mensagem. Porém o `Page.findcontrol("alert")` está me retornando `null` e não consigo entender o motivo.

.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="row">
            <div id="alert">


            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind:

```
 Message mensagens = new Message(this);
  mensagens.ShowMensagem("mensagem", "alerta");
```

Message.cs:

```
private Page pagina;
public Message(Page pagina) {
    this.pagina = pagina;
}

public void ShowMensagem(string mensagem, string tipo){
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)pagina.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1_alert");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que uma tag HTML seja visivel no code-behind você precisa colocar o atributo `runat="server"`, caso contrario só sera visivel no front-end.

---

Você pode misturar tags HTML com tags ASP.NET. A diferença é que tags HTML tem a opção de não precisarem de `runat="server"` para funcionar.

E isso é exatamente a função desse atributo, conseguir dizer para o ASP.NET o que ele deve fazer parsing.

Com isso é possivel atingir consistencia e extensibilidade.

Tem um post do Mike Schinkel explicando o `runat="server"` em inglês aqui: http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/whyrunatserverforaspnetpart2/